# I Cannot open file app debug apk on mobile phone

Tags: react-native, apk

i am creating app-debug.apk using this link https://dev.to/nitish173/how-to-generate-a-debug-apk-in-react-native-1gdg  and it perfectly create debug apk without generating error but when i download app it won't open on my cell phone , want why is this happening, it never happened before

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

1. `cd android`
2. `./gradlew clean`
3. `./gradlew assembleDebug`

apk file path:
`yourProject/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`

for release apk
`./gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: I tried this but still not working